# Tar directory is new error

Tags: linux, tar

I am trying to make a backup of two directories, /etc/httpd and /etc/letsencrypt

I am using the command

```
tar Pcfvg  httpd_backup.tar /etc/httpd/ /etc/letsencrypt/ >/dev/null
```

The redirect to /dev/null at the end was only added for debugging purposes.

I get error

```
tar: /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com: Directory is new
```

What does this error mean and how do I backup the directories successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-g` option creates incremental backups.

The message `Directory is new` is not an error, it's just a warning letting you know that a new directory was added to the archive which was not present in the previous backup.

Comment: I thought the -g option was to pass through gzip (I should have added .gzip at the end). I read the man page and what you said is correct, it was the -z option I wanted. Thank you very much.